# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException in hibernate program which ask for check mysql version

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Having the following Exception `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException` while programming in hibernate based program.

MySql version is 5.7.9 and my dialect is org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect.

Comment: Try with `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`

Comment: i have also tried with org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect but error it still comming

Comment: Please post your error stack and jdbc configuration.

Comment: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add, name, id) values ('godhra', 'raj', 1)' at line 1

Comment: post your code, stack trace and configuration in your question

Comment: Please post jdbc configuration in the question You have asked not in comments.

Comment: when i post my code it shows as it's so long

Comment: just related part is enough for each stack trace, config and code

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_schema</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

Comment: Data d=new Data();
  d.setName("raj");
  d.setAdd("godhra");
  SessionFactory ss=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  Session s=ss.openSession();
  s.beginTransaction();
  s.save(d);
  s.getTransaction().commit();

Comment: @Raj please post your error stack and configuration in Question not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

For building the `SessionFactory` object please use below code snippet and make sure you have `hibernate.cfg.xml` is in classpath.

```
try 
{
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                        .build());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(
            "There was an error building the factory");
}
```